# On npm start npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

Tags: reactjs

On npm start I am getting

> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found
> in:C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-07-05T11_54_44001Z-debug.log

How can I solve this?

Comment: Logical next step would go to that log file and read the actual error, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 3):

Type this command:

```
npm set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be in the right folder before you start react. Your main folder which includes public,src, package.json files should be targeted with changing directory and then npm start can be used

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem. And this is how I solved it.

Little scenario here.

I downloaded the other's project from GitHub ; did not started from the scratch. I extracted the zip. It created the folder react-stop-watcher with another folder react-stop-watcher.

Initially I hit the npm start command in

C:\Users\Lenovo\Downloads\react-stopwatch-master\

It throw the same npm ERR!. We need to get into

C:\Users\Lenovo\Downloads\react-stopwatch-master\react-stopwatch-master\

instead And then hit

- npm install
- npm start

And now my project is up and running.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem.
So, first I uninstalled the previous version by using

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

to ensure npx always uses the latest version.

And then reinstalled with the same code procedure:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Most probably I think you are using mysql but you not install mysql or not import the mysql.

I am also getting the same error but i resolve it by installing and importing the mysql.

try this

```
npm install mysql

import mysql in the file

var mysql = require('mysql');
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the error is just because of a network issue, might be your internet connection off or low internet connection try after some time that definitely works.

```
# to create project
npx create-react-app projectName  
# to run server
npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

Just follow this code

```
npm install
```

Then

```
npm audit fix
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true` to a .env file and that's it. Will solve it if you are using react

Answer (score 0):

cd to your project directory(myapp) where you have node_modules, public, src etc and try npm run.

Answer (score 0):

An error is coming coz you are not in the correct directory. Simply use cd(react project name) i.e.in may case its cd my-app(that I created using npm create-react-app my-app) and then simply run npm start

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qbsG.png)

Answer (score 0):

First You need to Delete all logs files in you Node cash folder
**C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs**

After that delete the package-lock.json file

run npm install and run your project

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are running npm start command from your project directory
i.e.
Reactnative Projects/myProject
make sure that you are in myProject directory before running npm start command. If you try to run from Reactnative Projects then the package.json file will not be founded and it will throw error message.
You can cange your directory with cd  command
i.e. cd myProject

Answer (score 0):

It actually occurs when you are not in a right folder. Like you create a folder React and inside it in a folder (my-app) you create all the necessary files then first you have to access the my-app folder(cd .\my-app) and then 'npm start' can work prefectly.

Answer (score -2):

just type the following in terminal:-
pwd,cd NameOfFolder